# Converting COM to EXE

Tags: assembly, masm

I have a program that loads itself as residential, and in COM realization everything is ok, but when i tried to convert my program i faced problem. The problem is that program closes without loading as residential, and it is caused by this line:

```
   call OLD_INT_PROC
```

where OLD_INT_PROC is a double word value that saves CS and IP of standard 1Ch interruption (from timer). So as i think this line of code calls standard interruption, and so then i can safely use my DS. Next two procedures: first is new interruption procedure(that shows time in top left corner of console window), second is set interruption procedure:

```
  NEW_TIMER_INT_PROC proc far
    pushf
    call OLD_INT_PROC 
    push DS
    push ES
    push AX
    push BX
    push CX
    push DX
    push DI

    mov AH, 2       ;Get current time 
    int 1Ah         ;CH - hours, CL - minutes, DH - seconds

    xor BX, BX
    mov AL, CH
    call BUF_FILL
    mov AL, CL
    call BUF_FILL
    mov AL, DH
    call BUF_FILL

            mov     ax,  0B800h             
            mov     es,  ax                 
            xor     di,  di                 
            xor     bx,  bx                 
            mov     ah,  1Bh                
    @@1:    mov    al,  BUF[bx]
            stosw              
            inc     bx         
            cmp     BUF[bx],  0
            jnz     @@1        

    @@5:                       
    ;mov DX, offset BUF
    ;call PRNT_MARKED_STRING
    pop DI
    pop DX
    pop CX
    pop BX
    pop AX
    pop ES
    pop DS
    popf
    mov AL, 20h
    out 20h, AL
    iret
NEW_TIMER_INT_PROC endp

LOAD_RESIDENT proc near
    mov IS_RESIDENTAL_STR, 'Y'              ;Defines special data for residental programm
    mov IS_RESIDENTAL_STR + 1, 'e'
    mov IS_RESIDENTAL_STR + 2, 'a'
    mov IS_RESIDENTAL_STR + 3, 'h'

    push ES
    mov AX, 351Ch                       ;Installing new interruption on 1Ch
    int 21h
    mov word ptr OLD_INT_PROC, BX
    mov word ptr OLD_INT_PROC + 2, ES
    pop ES

    push DS 
    mov DX, offset NEW_TIMER_INT_PROC
    mov AX, seg NEW_TIMER_INT_PROC
    mov DS, AX
    mov AX, 251Ch
    int 21h
    ;after i run this line in MASM program closes itself
    ;but if i comment problem line discribed above
    ;program loads ok, but my newly installed interruption
    ;doesnt work with my DS
    ;it loads time somewhere else, i'm considering it loads time in 
    ;DS = ES of standard interruption
    pop DS 

    mov AX, 3100h
    ;mov BX, ES
    mov DX, offset NEW_TIMER_INT_END_MARK
    ;sub DX, BX
    mov CL, 4
    shr DX, CL
    int 21h
LOAD_RESIDENT endp
```

I work with MASM, because teacher said so. :)

Answer (score 1):

Calling OLD_INT_PROC first could be an issue since it exits via iret, and your own handler is also exiting with an iret. You could have your code run first, then restore all the registers and do a far jump to OLD_INT_PROC.

Also, I'm not sure about using a terminate and stay resident program with .EXE, which includes a data segment, code segment, and stack segment, versus a .COM which is just a single segment.

Comment: There is a thing, why this code works in .COM program? And why after setting new 1Ch interruption in .EXE  and my handler works ok without problem line of code, but it seems like i didn't recover DS segment register, becouse the clocks are shown but with some gurbage.

Comment: With a .COM program, all the segments are normally set to the same value, cs == ds == es == ss. WIth a .EXE, you can group data and stack to be the same segment, but usually cs will not equal ds or ss. The assembler will generate a constant that you can use to load into ds or ss, so setting the segment registers can be done. The terminate and stay resident call uses cs and dx, so you may have to adjust dx based on where the actual end of the exe is relative to cs.

Comment: Ok i think i understood. But there is another problem. How to free memory for .EXE, for .COM I used 49h of int21h. But how i can do the same for .EXE. My .EXE has structure like STACK SEG-CODE SEG and when i try to free unused memory i move PSP addres to ES and use 49h but nothing happens. Or i need to use 49h with all my segments:  STACK SEG and CODE SEG?

Comment: You only use one call to release memory, terminate program, but stay resident. You need to set dx so that cs:dx points just past the end of your program.

Comment: I meant to free memory after i set standart 1Ch   int procedure back. Is there way to do this with exe? The thing i have program that shows MCB blocks information. And after installing new 1Ch int procedure i can see that one new MCB block appearedand it related to my residential program. But after i tried to free memory (in my opinion unload resident) the MCB block related to residential program remained.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I recall that there were programs that could do that but I don't know what was involved.